# How to get an A href within JS

Tags: javascript

I'm using JS in the console and need to get the href from the links on a website.

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("product");

var array = []

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    array.push(elements[i].getElementsByTagName("a").href);
    console.log(array);
}
```

When I put `.href` chained to getElementsByTagName, it goes undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns collection of elements, not single element.

Try this:

```
array.push(elements[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the problem is, as previously noted, that you can't retrieve properties from individual elements returned in a NodeList without iterating over those elements, you could do it a little more concisely than above:

```
// using Array.prototype.map, with Function.prototype.call,
// to iterate over the results of the array-like NodeList returned
// document.querySelectorAll(), and storing the returned values
// in an array:
var array = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.product a'), function (aElement) {
    // returning the href property of the <a> elements to the array:
    return aElement.href;
});

console.log(array); // ["http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#internalLink", "http://www.google.com/", "http://meta.stackoverflow.com/"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qhaewa5v/).

With the following HTML:

```
<div class="product"> <a href="#internalLink">Internal link</a>    
</div>
<div class="product"> <a href="//www.google.com/">Link to Google</a>    
</div>
<div class="product"> <a href="//meta.stackoverflow.com">Link to Meta</a>    
</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).